# Question regarding loan tape data when thinking about providing credit facility to bank

Tags: fixed-income, investment, investing

I have few questions regarding loan tape data such as this one: [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuKcT.jpg)

Say that I as a fund want to provide a credit facility to this bank and am given this loan tape data.

(1) What observations / analyses can I do on this data to learn more about the bank's origination over time? (Volume, loan characteristics, etc.)

(2) What additional data should I want from the bank to inform my underwriting decision?

(3) What would I need to know about using this collateral to back the credit facility?